# Ubuntu 18.04 how to disable power save?

Tags: wireless, power-management, settings

I have a wireless mouse, but Ubuntu shows, that it has 5% battery, and as a result is dimming after 30 sec of inactive. How can I turn it off?

**SOLUTION:**

Download some software to control behaviour of your device (in my case it was SetPoint) and then change the right things in settings there(in my case I had to disable notifications). If you cannot run the software on your OS as it was in my case. You can use Virtual Machine.

Thanks to @PRATAP for help.

Comment: Please don't add "solution" to question. Instead remove it from the question and add by clicking "Answer your question" button below. It's completely fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to system Settings, Power, in the Power Saving area you will find "Dim Screen When Inactive" Turn it off.[image]

Comment: I have turned it off. It doesn't work.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 7559. There is no Bios settings controlling this.

Comment: My laptop doesn't have touch screen. I'm not able to get into BIOS in Ubuntu. I can press F2, F12, fn+F2, esc, fn+esc, F1, fn+F1, but no one works. Is it possible like in windows to enter Bios through OS?

Comment: After 30sec of inactivity when I press any key it resuming. The  brightness screen is just lower. For instance normally I have 80% brightness and when it dim I have 20%. - that's what I mean saying that my screen is dimming.

Comment: I don't see the Dell logo. I have fast boot enabled in BIOS., but I press the keys immediately after turn computer on.

Comment: After install Ubuntu I wanted to get into BIOS. I've checked all possible combinations. Having Ubuntu with fast boot enabled I'm not able to get into BIOS. I need a windows OS to get into BIOS. (but currently I have only Ubuntu)

Comment: I know. But Ubuntu had to do something with my BIOS, beacuse even when I unplug hardware disk,  I'm not able to get into BIOS. The manual says only how can I can access BIOS via windows.

Comment: I've checked all possible combinations. Trust me it's not problem with wrong key pressed.

Comment: Reset CMOS also didn't help me.

Comment: I can use bootable usb, beacuse in my boot section I have set 1. USB 2. Hard drive. But I'm not sure how do you want to get into BIOS via booting menu.

Comment: I have restarted OS whole time I had pressed shift key until the OS brought me to login panel. Any recovery mode or something else didn't popup.

Comment: @Newb1996 It's a BIOS problem now which is off-topic here but on topic [there](htttps://superuser.com)  +1 to PRATAP for the good answer! **:-)**

Comment: Hi, in my grub menu I have just Ubuntu, mem-test and advanced options. In the advanced options I have recovery mode. But I don't know how can I get to BIOS through this.

Comment: I did it before. Like 2-3 days ago. I could see the grub menu whole time, but there is no option like BIOS.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 alone. https://www63.zippyshare.com/v/Mgq3Uqb4/file.html . I don't have there an option system settings.

Comment: But I remember, that in BIOS I hadn't an option like power managment, brightness control, or something like that. And my main purpose is to prevent dimming. So maybe, there is a way to do it? If I unplug my mouse then everything backs to normal, but when I have plugged in my wifi mouse, the screen dim after 30s.

Comment: It's a wireless mouse. - I need to plug special usb and then the mouse using wifi connect to this.

Comment: Try discharge your battery to 5%. Ubuntu shows, that my mouse has 5% battery, but in fact I'm using my mouse since 4 days.

Comment: Yes.  Settings -> Power -> Devices

Comment: https://www102.zippyshare.com/v/52GjDTz7/file.html As you wish :P Maybe just some devices are supported for this option.

Comment: @PRATAP Thanks, it helped me. I downloaded this program on Virtual Machine and changed some options there. Now everything is fine! Thank you very much :D