# Corsair Dark Core RGB Mouse

Tags: drivers, mouse

Hey guys I am pretty new to Ubuntu but I have a Corsair Dark Core RGB mouse (not that a am concerned about the RGB lights). I want to have back functionality of the side forward and backward (page navigation buttons) on the side of my mouse. I've downloaded the CBT-Next software it worked to get the RBG on my keyboard working but no options to get my mouse side buttons to work.

I did try messing with xbindkey but I am not quite sure how to get it to work, so if you are able to help me understand how to get this going. Please send help.

Comment: CBT-Next software is provided by mouse vendor and do they have support for Ubuntu?

Comment: little related https://askubuntu.com/q/1131790/739431

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this helps but I've been able to configure the mouse using the native app iCUE on Windows 10. I've set some profiles with key mappings there and then uploaded to the device, you can save up to 3 different profiles with remappings, light effects and dpi settings. After saving that, the profiles are available to use from any OS. Right now I'm using ubuntu 18.04 as my main OS with the settings saved in the device. Pretty neat. May be you could configure your mouse from a VM and then use it on any OS.