# Keyboard specific keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am using a **Creative Sound BlasterX Vanguard K08** keyboard. Keys such as turn up/down the volume, mute are working fine on the keyboard. The keyboard comes with 5 extra keys, namely, M1 - M5. I've tried to map the keys, but when I press them I get no response in any key mapping interface. Is it possible to activate them, so I can map them to whatever I want?

I can only find keyboard drivers for windows, though, in Ubuntu, it works out of the box on ordinary keys.

Btw I have ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hi, I have gone through the vendor/ manufacturer website and found that its support is only for windows.. the M1 fo M5 keys are called Macro Keys and can be configured through their software designed for Windows OS only.. i guess by default Macro Keys are 0ff.. you need to Use Windows 0S and turn on and assign the key mapping as you want and then see in Ubuntu whether it is working or not.. a similar cases are.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1042301/739431 https://askubuntu.com/q/1131790/739431

Comment: Hi, Kindly let us know the progress when you attempt any trails..

Comment: You could use `xev` to see the keyboard events, or (my favourite, but beware the learning curve) is to use `emacs` and `^H-k` (the `describe-key` function).