# Media keys not registered

Tags: keyboard, volume-control, media

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I am using a Creative Sound BlasterX Vanguard K08 keyboard. I have issue that media keys not working for me. It worked before with windows and manjaro.
I want to use volume-up and volume-down keys(for this keyboard scroll-wheel). I tried `showkey` and `xev` and they didn't show any key strokes.
I tried to use `dconf-editor` to to clear `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` and `XF86AudioLowerVolume`, but this didn't helped.
I have found that media keys is working for someone: [Keyboard specific keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143688/keyboard-specific-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Gnome is abstracting the low level media key press events away from individual programs, and using dbus instead. There is quite a bit of workaround to get the "old way" back.

BUT, There is a bug in gnome-settings-daemon that was corrected in version 3.32.1. Ubuntu 19+ pulls in the fixed version, so anyone running 18 or below is affected, unless they patch GSD.

See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1241511/619638